# Show that $\mathbb R$ is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space of infinite dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

because $\mathbb Q$ is countable, we can show that the subspace of $\mathbb R$ generated by any countable subset of $\mathbb R$ must be countable. Because $\mathbb R$ itself is uncountable, no countable set can be a basis for $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Is my answer sufficient or is further argument needed?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Somewhere in here you'd better make it explicit that only *finite* linear combinations of basis elements are allowed. How do you need to use that?

Comment: Hint: Given a field $k$, and a $k$-vector space $V$, a subset $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$ is a basis for $V$ if and only if the function $k^n \to V$ that sends $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in k^n$ to $a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$, is a bijection (in particular, $|k^n| = |V|$).

Comment: Yes, it's a valid argument.

Comment: @TedShifrin  it's an exercise list

Comment: If you are answering an exercise, then don't say "we can show that ..." without actually giving the proof of "...". If you really think "..." doesn't need proof, then say "clearly ...". "We can show that ..." is for papers and books, where authors are allowed to set implicit exercises for their readers.

Comment: @azif00: this isn't about finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @RobArthan Didn't know that, thanks

Comment: @RobArthan I know that, the proof could begin with "If $\mathbb R$ were a finite-dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space, then...". By the way, instead of "Hint" I should have said "Another way".